# Conflicting results in SPSS vs python and R for kolmogorov-smirnov uniform-distribution

Tags: python, r, spss, uniform-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov

I try to reproduce the same result on the same data file with different packages.

```
package mean     std      kstest   p
python  0.025416 1.034294 0.019337 0.8487
r       0.025416 1.034812 0.019337 0.8487
spss    0.025416 1.034812 0.032827 0.0129
```

Why spss gives different results?

Python code: `scipy.stats.kstest(x, 'norm')`.
R code: `ks.test(x,"pnorm")`.
SPSS code: `NPAR TESTS /K-S(NORMAL)=x.`
The same result can be reproduced choosing: Analyze->Nonparametric Tests->Legacy Dialogs->1-Sample K-S